# Can't open unity project

Tags: unity-game-engine, dump

1.system:Windows 7 64 bit
2.unity :5.3.8f1

---

When I open a old unity project, it prompts like this:[image]

I clicked continue, but after a while there was an error:
[image]

"error.log" file:
[image]

"Editor.log" file:[image]
[image]

---

I try to clone project files again, and reinstall unity5.3.8f1, and restart computer, but it still always happen error when I open my old project.
It is a team's project, they also install unity5.3.8f1 and use win7, but they did not make any mistakes.
Plesase help me, thanks.

Comment: Can you create new project with 5.3.8f1?

Comment: Yes, it can be used normally.But can't open old project.Also, I use the OpenVPN remote company computer,will it make any difference?

Comment: I don't think so. I suggest you download 5.1 then load save your 5.0 project.  Download Unity 5.2 then load and save the 5.1 project. Finally, download and 5.3 and load the 5.2 project. This might work for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. Also, I confirm, in the company computer, open directly without problems, personal computer through the OpenVPN remote desktop open, will be reported wrong